# Flutter commands not showing anything

Tags: powershell, flutter

When I type **flutter --version** or **flutter doctor** in powershell, nothing is showing, a command prompt like window is opened for half a second and goes.
I can't see the output of the commands
I have downloaded flutter.
After the download when I first run the commands it was working in powershell and after that it is not working.please help I am a beginner.

Comment: did you add flutter path to your environment variable?

Comment: yes I did and it worked for the first time when I ran the command, after that the problem came

Answer (score 0):

Flutter require the powershell version 5.0 or newer.So check the version and update and also type that command in command prompt to check flutter is installed successfully or not.

Comment: Yes I checked, and the commands ran perfectly the first time I typed, after that when I typed the command next day, the above problem came